# can I concatenate some text with auto increment id (primary key)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Here i have a model called **"Something"** it has primary key column id, that will auto generate id.

```
class Something:
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=true)
```

this will generate integers like **1,2,3**

But, I want something like "**someConst1**","**someConst2**","**someConst3**", Here **someConst** is the constant value that will never change anymore.

Is there any way to concatenate some text with auto generated id ?

Comment: why would you want to do something like this ? Instead, while accessing you can explicitly acess it as `"someConst%s" % id` ?

Answer (score 0):

By default django add a `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` for each model.

You can create your own id and set this putting `primary_key = True`

reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

One way is override the save method like this:

```
class Xpto(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key = True)
    autonum = models.IntegerField()
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        last_autonum = Xpto.objects.all().order_by("-autonum")
        #Use this if just to add the first record, then use just last_autonum=last_autonum[0].autonum
        if last_autonum.count():
            last_autonum=last_autonum[0].autonum
        else:
            last_autonum = 0
        self.id = 'someConst%d' % (last_autonum + 1)
        self.autonum = last_autonum + 1
        super(Xpto,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Remember that in the first time you run this it will raise an exception cause you don't have any records in this table. You can add so.

Comment: It says autofields must have primary_key=True, that means autonum shuold be a primary key..

Comment: i want some auto generate char field thats why.

Comment: I added some improvements, without the AutoField.

Comment: I think this will increment at each update for the object, should be only for creation?